# How to Embedded Autodesk Viewer on winform vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, autocad, autodesk, autocad-plugin

I need to finish an older project where AutoDesk Viewer is Embedded on a Winform.
This project was done several years ago using what I assumed an older version of Autodesk. I can see on the Reference that they have a AxACCTRLLib.AxAcCtrl.dll. I downloaded autodesk design review 2013. My question is the .dll library for the embedded view has a diferent name?. Because I cannot find any with the same name of library as show above. This project was in a different computer so thats why I had to install the new autocad etc..

Below is a screenshot of the project showing the autodesk viewwer control. 
Any Help please I have been researching for a while now without any success

[image: Winform AutoDeskVwr embedded]

Comment: Who care's if the name is different that doesn't matter. Change the reference to the new one.

Comment: @436f6465786572 I dont care either if the name is different i just want to know which one I need to reference to so im able to embed it.

Comment: Do you need large detailed preview or simple more grainy preview which to give you an idea of the contents of the dwg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add COM reference to c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\DwgViewrAcCtrl.dll